# Magento 2.2: How can I override "checkout.item.price.unit" and "checkout.item.price.row" in the cart?

Tags: magento2, module, layout, overrides, phtml

My goal is to switch out the **.phtml** files: **magento_module-wee::item/price/unit.phtml** as well as **magento_module-wee::item/price/row.phtml** with my own custom ones and change how the prices are displayed in the cart.

My approach so far was to use:
**app\code\Vendor\Module\view\frontend\layout\checkout_item_price_renderers.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.item.price.unit">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::item/price/unit.phtml</argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.item.price.row"> 
        <arguments>
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::item/price/row.phtml</argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</page>
```

**Edit2: NOTE! The code above should work but does NOT (as I just found out). `<action method="setTemplate">` (which is deprecated) has to be used (until the above code works as advertised) aparently.**

And have the custom **row.phtml** as well as **unit.phtml** located at:
**app\code\Vendor\Module\view\frontend\templates\item\price\**

I also tried to change `<arguments>` to `<action method="setTemplate">`, but whatever I tried so far - the "vanilla" module (module-weee) and its phtml file versions are used.

Any ideas how to get my phtml files rendered instead?

**Edit1:** Reading Hit's answer, I realized that I should probably post my entire module, not only the part, where I believe the fault lies. Sorry for my posting inexperience!

**app\code\Vendor\Module\etc\module.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
            <module name="Magento_Weee"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**app\code\Vendor\Module\registration.php:**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 
    'Vendor_Module',
    __DIR__
);
```

**app\code\Vendor\Module\composer.json**:

```
{
    "name": "vendor/module",
    "description": "Description",
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.0.13|>=7.1.1",
        "magento/framework": "101.0.*"
    },
    "repository": {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
          "registration.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "Vendor\\Module\\": ""
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

follow below steps.

**step 1**) create a custom module if not create like Vendor/Frontendsample

**2) create registration.php**

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_Frontendsample',
    __DIR__
);
```

**3) create module.xml under etc folder**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Frontendsample" setup_version="1.0.0"></module>
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
        </sequence>
</config>
```

**4) create checkout_item_price_renderers.xml under Vendor/Frontendsample/view/frontend/layout/**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.item.price.unit">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Frontendsample::item/price/unit.phtml</argument>
            </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.item.price.row">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Frontendsample::item/price/row.phtml</argument>
            </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**5) paste row.phtml and unit.phtml** files under **Vendor/Frontendsample/view/frontend/templates/item/price/** from core folder **vendor/magento/module-weee/view/frontend/templates/item/price**

6) run this command **php bin/magento setup:upgrade && php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f**

you can take reference code from [here](https://github.com/hitesh-srtpl/magento225-demo/tree/master/app/code/Vendor.zip)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! Your version uses `<action>` instead of argument and forces a Magento_Checkout in sequence (I tried to sequence Magento_weee). But apart from that they are indentical - and do not work.

Comment: you can also use **<arguments>** instead of **<action>** see my updated answer

Comment: The phtml rendered is still: vendor/magento/module-weee/view/frontend/templates/item/price/unit.phtml - our modules are basically the same, but do not seem to work.

Comment: which Magento version are you using? did you run basic commands of Magento like **php bin/magento setup:upgrade && php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f** is your module listed in etc/config.xml? did you got any error in log/exception.log or system.log? might be you missed something small, As I have tested in magento 2.2.6

Comment: You are right! I did not run the "php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f" as my magento cli told me that it (php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy) is unnecessary in developer mode - BUT - now it works! Thank you!

Comment: you are welcome